MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite) i'm stuck
I am develop a flutter application for ASD Classification based on face images. I have been stuck for 2 weeks with the problem "missingpluginexception (no implementation found for the load loading method in the tflite channel)". I have placed the model and label path correctly. I hope someone can help me 
Future<void> loadModel() async {
    try {
      await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: 'assets/asd.tflite', 
        labels: 'assets/label.txt', 
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Failed to load model: $e");
    }
  }

  // Function to perform image classification
  Future<void> classifyImage(File image) async {
    try {
      var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
        path: image.path,
        numResults: 2, // Number of classification results
      );
      setState(() {
        _output = output;
        _loading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Failed to classify image: $e");
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  tflite: ^1.1.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_core: ^2.32.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.20.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  provider: ^6.1.2
  flutter_svg: 2.0.10+1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.5
  firebase_storage: ^11.7.7
  image_cropper: ^7.0.4
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3


I have tried running the application using vscode and android studio with an android emulator, but there are no signs that the model is being read. Maybe there are some other settings in build.gradle or other files that I missed. Because this is my first flutter application that uses tflite 

stop the running build and relaunch it again

I'm tired of trying to build and relaunch, still no success :)

why dont you try tflite_flutter instead of tflite? tflite did not received any update since 3 years.
